# Could not load type 'WingTipToys.Global_asax'

Tags: parsing, global-asax

I used to be a hobby programmer and still am. But, now I am trying to learn web application development and have been going through the first steps of Wingtiptoys project on MS site. After having done what was asked of me by the site and running the project for the first time...I get the below error on my browser.

QUOTE

Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'WingTipToys.Global_asax'.

Source Error:

Line 1:  <%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.vb" Inherits="WingTipToys.Global_asax" Language="vb" %>

Source File: /global.asax    Line: 1

UNQUOTE

Can anyone help?

Thanks & Best Regards
Rajeev

Comment: Can you link to the website you are using?

Comment: I tried going to the link mentioned above on my pc and nothing happens...I also removed the "default.aspx"...and still nothing happening. Does this have anything to do with IIS?  Below is the error page that came up why? 
Hmmm... cannot reach this page
Try this
Make sure that you’ve got the right web address: http://localhost:44311
Search for "http://localhost:44311" on Bing
Refresh the page
Details 
Report this issue

Privacy statement

Comment: Does any one have any idea on how to go forward? Any help/guidance will be helpful

Comment: Unfortunately, if no-one can access the code, no-one can help.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Michelle for trying to help and please accept my appology for not realizing that you were looking for the code as I assumed this was a common error for biginners. Anyways...below is the code from Global.asax.vb and at the very bottom is the code  from Global.asax

```
Namespace WingTipToys
Public Class [Global]
Inherits HttpApplication

Private Sub Application_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes)
BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles)
Database.SetInitializer(New ProductDatabaseInitializer)
End Sub
End Class
End Namespace
```

Here is the code from Global.asax

```
<%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.vb" Inherits="WingTipToys.Global.asax" language="vb" %>
```